# Use variables from PropertyGroup in csproj in an Postbuild event

Tags: c#, .net-core, msbuild, csproj

In .csproj file is set:

```
<PropertyGroup>     
  <Company>Acme</Company>
  <Product>NextBigThing</Product> 
</PropertyGroup>
```

I would like use variables in following Post-Build-Event:

```
<Target Name="PostBuild" AfterTargets="PostBuildEvent">
  <Exec Command="xcopy <source> %AppData%\<Company>\<Product>\" />
</Target>
```

How to use Company and Product variable as part of path in Post-Build-Event?

Answer (score 1):

**My solution using PowerShell 7**

You need to create a PowerShell script inside of project folder, for this example is "**PostBuild.ps1**". This script will be called in PostbuildEvents property.

For MsBuild properties
https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/visualstudio/ide/how-to-specify-build-events-csharp?view=vs-2022

Download Powershell
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/install/installing-powershell-on-windows?view=powershell-7.3

---

> **First Solution** Reading the Project'XML and retrieving the properties.

**Your project files**

[image: project]

**Your project XML**

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
        <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
        <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
        <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
        <Company>Acme</Company>
        <Product>NextBigThing</Product>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <Target Name="PostBuild" AfterTargets="PostBuildEvent">
        <Exec Command="pwsh -NoLogo -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command &quot;./PostBuild.ps1 -ProjectFileName $(ProjectFileName)&quot;" />
    </Target>

</Project>
```

[image: project xml]

**Your project properties - Visual studio**

The command to call "**PostBuild.ps1**" is

```
pwsh -NoLogo -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "./PostBuild.ps1 -ProjectFileName $(ProjectFileName)"
```

[image: properties]

**PostBuild.ps1 - Code**

```
[CmdletBinding()]
param (
    [Parameter()]
    [string]
    $ProjectFileName
)

Write-Host "█ ProjectFileName from parameters: $ProjectFileName"

$basePath = "//Project/PropertyGroup"
$companyLabel = "Company"
$productLabel = "Product"

if (!(Test-Path $ProjectFileName -PathType Leaf) -or (!"$ProjectFileName".EndsWith(".csproj"))) {
    throw "Invalid file `"$ProjectFileName`"."
}

[System.Xml.XmlDocument] $doc = [System.Xml.XmlDocument]::new()
$doc.PreserveWhitespace = $true
$doc.Load($ProjectFilename)
$company = $doc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("$basePath/$companyLabel").InnerText
$product = $doc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("$basePath/$productLabel").InnerText

Write-Host "█ command: xcopy ""$PSScriptRoot"" ""%AppData%\$company\$product\"""
```

**Output**

```
1>------ Rebuild All started: Project: VariablesInPostBuildEvents, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
Restored C:\Users\Megam\Desktop\so an\VariablesInPostBuildEvents\VariablesInPostBuildEvents.csproj (in 3 ms).
1>VariablesInPostBuildEvents -> C:\Users\Megam\Desktop\so an\VariablesInPostBuildEvents\bin\Debug\net7.0\VariablesInPostBuildEvents.dll
1>█ ProjectFileName from parameters: VariablesInPostBuildEvents.csproj
1>█ command: xcopy "C:\Users\Megam\Desktop\so an\VariablesInPostBuildEvents" "%AppData%\Acme\NextBigThing\"
========== Rebuild All: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
========== Elapsed 00:01.628 ==========
```

[image: out]

---

> **Second Solution** Company and Product are MSBuild known properties. It can be included in command.

Same file structure

**Command in PostBuildEvents**

```
pwsh -NoLogo -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "./PostBuild.ps1 -Company $(Company) -Product $(Product)"
```

**PostBuild.ps1**

```
[CmdletBinding()]
param (
    [Parameter()]
    [string]
    $Company,

    [Parameter()]
    [string]
    $Product
)

Write-Host "█ Company: $Company"
Write-Host "█ Company: $Product"
Write-Host "█ command: xcopy ""$PSScriptRoot"" ""%AppData%\$company\$product\"""
```

**Output**

```
Rebuild started...
1>------ Rebuild All started: Project: VariablesInPostBuildEvents, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
Restored C:\Users\Megam\Desktop\so an\VariablesInPostBuildEvents\VariablesInPostBuildEvents.csproj (in 2 ms).
1>VariablesInPostBuildEvents -> C:\Users\Megam\Desktop\so an\VariablesInPostBuildEvents\bin\Debug\net7.0\VariablesInPostBuildEvents.dll
1>█ Company: Acme
1>█ Company: NextBigThing
1>█ command: xcopy "C:\Users\Megam\Desktop\so an\VariablesInPostBuildEvents" "%AppData%\Acme\NextBigThing\"
========== Rebuild All: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
========== Elapsed 00:02.728 ==========
```

[image: output]

Comment: It's a good answer but the solution got problematic when passing variables that may contains spaces or escape characters. For example to pass the solution directory as a parameter I had to single quote it like the following: `-Command "./PostBuild.ps1 -SolutionDir '$(SolutionDir)'"`

Answer (score 0):

Just use `$(<VariableName>)` like

```
  <Exec Command="xcopy ... \$(Company)\$(Product)\ ..." />
```

based on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-properties?view=vs-2022

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <Company>Acme</Company>
    <Product>NextBigThing</Product>
</PropertyGroup>

<Target Name="PostBuild" AfterTargets="PostBuildEvent">
    <Exec Command="xcopy.exe SOME_FILE_PATH %AppData%\$(Company)\$(Product)\ /Y" />
</Target>
```

You need to add `\` after `$(Product)` so Windows know that is a folder and `/Y` to override already existing files.